# Define methods under global unit. Disadvantages?

Tags: specman

I want to define global methods.
For that i define their signature under global unit.
What are the disadvantages of doing so ?
Why does it not recommended ?

Answer (score 2):

One disadvantage of using global methods might be that they can be called without explicitly stating the object (just `foo()` rather than `global.foo()`), and this is error prone. For example, if your struct happens to have its own method with the same name, such a call is treated as a call to the struct method rather than the global method.

Speaking more generally, one of the principles in object oriented programming is that functions (methods) belong to some object/class rather than being global.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `sn_utils` instead. It is also a singleton like `global`, but forces you to use its instance name: `utils.foo()`.
You need to be aware not to pollute its namespace, e.g. use `<evc-name>_foo()` as method name.